# Ionic 3 loading controller backdrop design

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working with Ionic 3 on iPhones (iOS 10/11), and I'd like to know if I can have different styles/designs of the loading controller backdrop. I need in some places the backdrop to cover the full height of the screen and in some places only the middle (part of the screen).

so far I'm doing this via the app.scss:

```
.loading-ios {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  position: fixed;
  top: 44px;
  bottom: 49.5px;
}
```

But this way the backdrop is the same everywhere. Trying to do this locally in local scss files doesn't work, as app.scss overwrites them (naturally).

Any way to do it?

Here's a sample add, but with commented out SCSS code, as I don't know where to add custom styles within STackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-sqou2x

Comment: Could you please create a Stackblitz project so we can test a few things there?

Comment: You can add special class for each loading by option `cssClass` then style for it.

Comment: @Duannx as far as I know, cssClass only styles the inner box/area of the loader, not the backdrop. I need the backdrop to cover 100% and in some case only 70% of the screen height.

Comment: @sebaferreras I've created it at https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-sqou2x, but I don't know where to add my custom SCSS code, I couldn't find any stylesheet files.

Comment: @Dimitri: `cssClass` add the class to `ion-loading` so you can  definitely apply style for the backdrop. Just inspect into loading element and find the class.

Comment: @Duannx  Can you please provide a code snippet please as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add a class to your loading by `cssClass`:

```
this.loadingCtrl.create({
     content: "login",
     cssClass: "my-loading"
}).present();
```

Second, add style for  `.my-loading` in `app.scss`:

```
.my-loading {
    ion-backdrop {
        top: 15%;
        height: 70%; 
    }
}
```